# NuGet version range - always get the package with the highest revision number

Tags: nuget

I have declared the following package reference

```
<PackageReference Include="Abc.Defg" Version="9.9.5.*" />
```

With the desire that it should pick exactly a version `9.9.5` followed by the highest revision number it can  find eg. `9.9.5.1234`
Any package that doesn't start with `9.9.5.` should be invalid eg. `9.9.6.0` or `9.9.4.0`

I am getting the following message when I call `nuget CLI` command `nuget restore` but fail to understand how exactly to fix the warning and still get my desired result

> WARNING: NU1604: Project dependency Abc.Defg does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.

FYI, in case it makes a difference, the package version numer isn't declared directly as shown above but instead it is declared in a `Directory.Build.props` as a `Property`.

```
<MyVersion>9.9.5.*</MyVersion>
```

Which is than used as the following

```
<PackageReference Include="Abc.Defg" Version="$(MyVersion)" />
```

Is it possible to fix this with only one version number or do I need to change it to something like this

```
[9.9.5,9.9.6)
```

Which, if I am correct, translates to include `9.9.5.0` (0 can be omitted) and everything up to exclusively `9.9.6`, so from `9.9.5.0` till `9.9.5.65534` should be valid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 9.9.5.* version extends the version range not just up, but down as well.

Lower version numbers that match this wildcard version constraint may not have the required "**Abc.Defg**" dependency.

The lower version number may need to be set to a version that covers this dependency, perhaps ...

```
(9.9.5.4, 9.9.5.*)
```